# How do I hide past posts in a custom Wordpress loop AND display X number of upcoming posts?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to display a list of posts in Wordpress with dates that are equal to or *greater than* today - the purpose is to list out upcoming events.

Here's the code I have right now:

```
// Get the current date
    $current_date = date('M d, Y');
    $current_date = strtotime( $current_date );

    // Get the event date
    $post_date = get_the_time('M d, Y');
    $post_date = strtotime( $post_date );

    query_posts(array('category_name' => 'events',
                    'meta_query' => array(
                        array(
                         'key' => $post_date,
                         'value'=> $current_date,
                         'compare'=>'>='
                         )
                    ),
                    'showposts' => 4,
                    'orderby' => 'date', 
                    'order' => ASC));

    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
```

As you can see, I'm grabbing the current date and the date of the post. I know this code works, because I had it functioning *mostly* in the following format:

```
// Get the current date
$current_date = date('M d, Y');
$current_date = strtotime( $current_date );

query_posts(array('category_name' => 'events',
'showposts' => 4,
'orderby' => 'date', 
'order' => ASC));

while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 

// Get the date
$post_date = get_the_time('M d, Y');
$post_date = strtotime( $post_date );

// If older than current date, don't show it
if( $post_date >= $current_date ):
```

But the problem with that is that it finds the posts, then compares them to the current date. So if I want to show 4 of my 10 posts, but 3 are hidden because they're in the past, I'm actually only displaying 1 post here.

I need to compare to the current date *then* show 4 posts from the result of that calculation.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this you can use a `date_query` as part of your `query_posts()` call (in place of the `meta_query`).

This will then eliminate the need to check the date of `Posts` once a query has been run, so you should always get the four that you are seeking.

```
$today = getdate();
$args = array(
    'date_query'        => array(
        array(
            'year'      => $today["year"],
            'month'     => $today["mon"],
            'day'       => $today["mday"],
            'compare'   => '>=',
        ),
    ),
    'posts_per_page'    => 4,
    'orderby'           => 'date', 
    'order'             => ASC
);
query_posts($args);
```

**Note:** I'd strongly recommend reviewing the [`WP_Query` codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) for further information as there are some very useful parameters in there. These can help you to further refine the `Posts` that are returned and include the likes of `post_type`, `post_status` and `cat`. Of course not all of these will be relevant to you in all situations (or possibly at all), but it's still worth a read.

**Caution:** Please be aware that `posts_per_page` replaced <s>`show_posts`</s> some time ago.

## Update

You mention in the comments that the above code is working, but only one `Post` is being retrieved. My initial thoughts are that this is caused by one of two things -

1. You only have one future `Post`, and thus there are no more to show.
2. Something is hooking your query and changing the `LIMIT` portion.

I suggest viewing the query that was passed to `MySQL` as soon as it is made. To do this, add the following line directly below `query_posts($args)` and reload your page. -

```
global $wpdb;
echo '<pre>'; print_r($wpdb->last_query); echo '<pre>';
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This definitely points me in the right direction, though oddly now I'm only getting the next upcoming post and no others - regardless of what I put for the 'post_per_page'. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: This query is checking for `Posts` where the `post_date` is in the future (I.e. scheduled posts). I've just re-read your question and fear I may have misinterpreted it; Do you add an event date to a Custom Value (meta_key/value pair), and you want to get the next four upcoming events based on that?

Comment: I have a plugin installed that shows future posts as published. The code you shared above does indeed show a post that is in the future, but it only shows the one, not 4 like it should.

Comment: I've added an update to my answer to try and help you figure this out. Please post the resultant query in a comment so that I can see what is happening.

Comment: I appreciate you sticking with me on this! I added the extra code you mentioned above and got the following:

SELECT post_id, meta_key, meta_value FROM wp_cfwine_1postmeta WHERE post_id IN (63) ORDER BY meta_id ASC

Comment: Here is your problem - `WHERE post_id IN (63)`. `post_id` is unique, so there can only be one matching post for the query to return. Now you need to work out why this is being added to you're query, which I'm afraid to say is outside of the scope of this question. I'd suggest trying to disable plugins one at a time though, which will hopefully point you to the culprit.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm going to rethink this and take a different approach. I'm feeling there's a better way to add an event day (namely, custom fields) and using this "future posts" plugin is likely just complicating things.

Comment: I agree. You can just query `scheduled` Posts, you don't need a plugin for that at all. If you have other Posts that you schedule and don't want to show, you just need to create a custom field. Much cleaner, easier, quicker and safer. I'd appricate you marking this answer as correct though, as I do believe that I answered our original question. Thanks.